# How to change time zone setting of server

Tags: php, timezone

I try to fetch date from server

```
date('l, F j, Y  g:i A',strtotime($data_event->start_date));
```

It shows time zone EDT, how do i change it into Makkah Time zone. Please anyone out there for any suggestions.

Note: I prefer PHP language.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/rdlowrey/php-date-prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
date_default_timezone_set('');
```

That should do it for all your PHP code.

If you are using a database, the timezone for the database will probably be different as well. If you are using MySQL, you have to SET `time_zone = "+3:00"` query as soon as you open a database connection.

Answer (score 1):

Use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for this

Also you can use [Class datetimezone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

List of timezones http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

I think the `Asia/Riyadh` will apply for `Makkah` Try this one,

```
<?php
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Riyadh');
   date('l, F j, Y  g:i A',strtotime($data_event->start_date));
?>
```

Comment: I added date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Riyadh'), but it shows up AST instead makkah.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one

```
SET time_zone = "+3:00"
```

in your index.php file. You don't need to have access to your php.ini file.

Comment: what? where did you get this syntax?

Comment: @DevZer0: after (mysql) database connection